# Update columns in multiple rows

Tags: updates

I am trying to run this query bug it keeps failing; can't use table in the from clause.

```
update student s1 set tot_cred = (select total_cred from student s inner join taken t on s.id=t.id inner join transfer_course tc on (t.transfer_course_id, t.college_id) =   (tc.transfer_course_id, tc.college_id));
```

Any pointers appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:
I don't think the 'on' keyword allows multiple columns to be compared.
If it does it is news to me

```
update student s1 
set tot_cred = (select total_cred 
                from student s 
                    inner join taken t 
                        on s.id=t.id 
                    inner join transfer_course tc 
                        on t.transfer_course_id = tc.transfer_course_id
                            and t.college_id = tc.college_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update student s1
set s1.tot_cred =
  (select total_cred
   from student s
   inner join taken t
   on s.id=t.id
   inner join transfer_course tc
   on (t.transfer_course_id = tc.transfer_course_id)
   AND (t.college_id = tc.college_id)
  );
```